# Почему не приходит ответ

Tags: mysql

Есть база данных Serials в ней поля id и name_serial заполнены таким значением

```
id          name_serial
648        Любовь/Ненависть
```

пишу такой запрос

```
SELECT *
FROM `fl_serial`
WHERE `name_serial` = 'Любовь/Ненависть'
```

получаю такой ответ

```
MySQL вернула пустой результат (т.е. ноль строк).
```

почему и как это устранить

Comment: 1. Пропустили закрывающий апостроф 2. есть чувство, что в строке есть концевые/начальные проблемы.

Comment: @Doofy мне пока надо чистый mysql Запрос оформить. Я ведь вроде про php ничего неписал

Comment: @DmitriySimushev поправил кавычки просто не с копировались с запроса а в чем концевые начальные проблемы.

Comment: Поля заполнены в таблице, а не в базе данных. У Вас имя таблицы-то какое? Запрос должен быть: SELECT FROM * (имя таблицы)

Comment: `WHERE name_serial LIKE 'Любовь/Ненависть'` Выведет что то?

Comment: @ilyaplot да формируйте ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте функции сравнения строк, например LIKE.
Ваш запрос будет выглядеть так

```
SELECT *
FROM `fl_serial`
WHERE `name_serial` LIKE 'Любовь/Ненависть'
```

Comment: Ключевой вопрос _почему_ `LIKE` работает, а `=` -- нет.